# How to add several Frame within a ListView XAML

Tags: xaml, listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms, frame

I want to add several frames like the image below:

[image: Frame]

The problem is that these are inside a `<ListView>` and it does not allow me to add more than one inside the `<View>` tag

When I add the second I get the following error:

> The property 'View' is set more than once.

I attached a screenshot of how my LIstView is structured for greater detail and its respective code.

```
  <ListView 
                ItemsSource="{Binding Reportes}"
                SelectionMode="None"
                Margin="0,0,10,0"
                HasUnevenRows="true">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>  
                        <Frame
                            CornerRadius="15"
                            HasShadow="True"
                            Padding="5"
                            BackgroundColor="{StaticResource das.color.estado_primary}">                     
                            <StackLayout 
                                    Orientation="Horizontal"
                                    BackgroundColor="{StaticResource das.color.estado_primary}">
                                <Image
                                    Source="barrascf"
                                    HeightRequest="80"
                                    WidthRequest="80"
                                    Opacity="1">
                                </Image>
                                <StackLayout
                                    Orientation="Vertical"
                                    HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand"
                                    BackgroundColor="{StaticResource das.color.estado_primary}">
                                    <Label
                                            Text="{Binding ArticulosTotales}"
                                            TextColor="White">
                                    </Label>
                                    <Label
                                            Text="ARTICULOS TOTALES"
                                            TextColor="White">
                                    </Label>
                                </StackLayout>
                            </StackLayout>                       
                    </Frame>

                            <Frame
                            CornerRadius="15"
                            HasShadow="True"
                            Padding="5"
                            BackgroundColor="{StaticResource das.color.estado_primary}">
                                <StackLayout 
                                    Orientation="Horizontal"
                                    BackgroundColor="{StaticResource das.color.estado_primary}">
                                    <Image
                                    Source="barrascf"
                                    HeightRequest="80"
                                    WidthRequest="80"
                                    Opacity="1">
                                    </Image>
                                    <StackLayout
                                    Orientation="Vertical"
                                    HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand"
                                    BackgroundColor="{StaticResource das.color.estado_primary}">
                                        <Label
                                            Text="{Binding ArticulosTotales}"
                                            TextColor="White">
                                        </Label>
                                        <Label
                                            Text="ARTICULOS TOTALES"
                                            TextColor="White">
                                        </Label>
                                    </StackLayout>
                                </StackLayout>
                            </Frame>
                        </ViewCell>

                </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>                
            </ListView>
```

[image: Screenshoot]

What am I doing wrong? How should I structure my XAML code? any help for me?

Comment: use a Layout container (Stack, Grid, etc) to wrap your Frames within your ViewCell

Comment: Should each frame be a separate item in the ListView? Or do you want each ListView item showing several frames?

Comment: I want each item in the listview to show several @MaxHampton

Comment: you could suggest an answer? @Jason

Comment: putting the frames inside a StackLayout each one does not solve the problem @Jason

Comment: <ViewCell><StackLayout><Frame/><Frame/><Frame/></StackLayout></ViewCell>

Comment: this has solved my problem .... do you want to add an answer? @Jason

Answer (score 2, accepted):

any time you need to add multiple views to a control that only accepts a single child, you can do so by wrapping them in a Layout container (Stack, Grid etc)

```
<ViewCell>
  <StackLayout>
    <Frame/>
    <Frame/>
    <Frame/>
  </StackLayout>
</ViewCell>
```